# SystemError: E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: ubuntu, driver, printers, epson

I have Ubuntu 32 bit running on HP Pavilion. 
Today I brought EPSON Artisan 725 printer, I connected the usb cable to the printer. Driver utility popped up. It gave to two options for driver. I choose the recommended one.

It asked me for password before it could install the driver. Once I gave the password it shows following error:

> SystemError: E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

What could be the issue here. How to resolve it.

Comment: "Broken" means dependency resolution was inconclusive, "held" means you have manually instructed dpkg to not upgrade or remove them, hence it cannot come up with a resolution strategy. Without ant concrete details, neither can we. What does `sudo apt-get upgrade -f` do? (Create a backup before experimenting, though.)